# Spring Boot Config Client is not getting property from Config Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I was able to start Config Server, pointing my browser to http://localhost:8888/example/default, gives me:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "profiles": [
    "default"
  ],
  "label": null,
  "version": null,
  "state": null,
  "propertySources": [
    {
      "name": "classpath:/example.yaml",
      "source": {
        "example.mykey": "myvalue"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I assume the above should be enough to see that Config Server is up and running, and it contains "example.mykey" property, which I'm planning to use in the example client app. (Let me know if config server internals are also needed here).

The client app is as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleClientConfigApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleClientConfigApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    class ExampleController {

        @Value("${example.mykey}")
        private String value;

        @RequestMapping
        public String sayValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

The client app also has a bootstrap.yaml in its src/main/resources dir:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: example
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```

In my understanding, the above client app is configured to use 'example' app's 'default' profile configuration from config server. Yet, the this application fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'example.mykey' in value "${example.mykey}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
```

Why cannot it take this property from the Config Server? What am I missing?

=== UPDATE. Adding also client pom.xml, as requested in comments ===

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.jnetx</groupId>
<artifactId>example-config-client</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you please add your pom files and application / bootstrap configuration ? It is something strange. Nothing changed in spring client config, it still should be spring.cloud.config.uri. I just tried - everything works fine in your example.

Comment: Client pom.xml added, bootstrap.yaml was already provided.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After spending the whole day in vain, I finally tried something that made it work. Server config uri comes under `spring.config.uri` as opposed to non-working `spring.cloud.config.uri` (which is given in most examples). Maybe this has changed in spring boot 2.0.5, but this yaml works:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: example
  config:
    enabled: true
    uri: http://localhost:8888
```

Comment: It may use (and it probably it is using) the default configuration which is pointing to localhost:8888, I believe that something was wrong with your previous config. spring.config.uri is not resolving to nothing. prefix is still spring.cloud.config.uri. see: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/client/ConfigClientProperties.java

Comment: I have the same problems using 2.1.4, I tried your solution, but it still doesn't work for me, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar issue, you are missing a dependency **org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and then proceed with yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: example
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```